# Rails API + React Frontend - how to make CSRF cookie NOT httponly?

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, api, csrf, httponly

I have a Rails 6 API and a React frontend and I would like to keep `verify_authenticity_token` on all controller actions.

Backend sets CSRF token as follows in `application_controller.rb`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...

  include ActionController::Cookies
  after_action :set_csrf_cookie

  ...

  protected

  def verified_request?
    super || request.headers['X-CSRF-Token'] === cookies['X-CSRF-Token']
  end

  def set_csrf_cookie
    if protect_against_forgery? && current_user
      cookies['X-CSRF-Token'] = {
        value: form_authenticity_token,
        httponly: false
      }
    end
  end

end
```

Frontend is attempting to use [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) to retrieve cookies.  I have the following in a `cookies.js` file:

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'

const getCSRFToken = () => {
  window.Cookies = Cookies;
  const token = Cookies.get('X-CSRF-Token')

  return token
}

export default getCSRFToken
```

and I call this function when I create an Axios request.  The function to build the request takes params like method, url, data, etc.:

```
export const newAxiosIns = params => {
  // params will be a hash of various headers
  const defaultParams = {
    baseURL: baseUrl,
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
      common: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': getCSRFToken()
      }
    }
  }
  
  const axiosIns = axios.create(defaultParams)
  
  return axiosIns(params)
}
```

But the cookies end up being `httponly` in Chrome:
[image: screenshot showing httponly checked]

I wondered if it had to do with the form_authenticity_token, so I made a fake token with a value of 'faker' but that was also not `httponly`.

Thanks!

Comment: I used your code and the cookie is set correctly, to not `httponly`